# How to count transaction on the basis of bins and type

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot, case

I have the following table in MySQL DB.

[image]

I need to construct a report considering bins(on the basis of amount and type)
[image]

I have tried using the following code

```
select TYPE, 
        case when TYPE is null
            then @total := count(*)
            else count(*)
        end as counter
    from mytable
    group by TYPE
    with rollup
```

However, I am not able to get the report in the above-required format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the buckets in a subquery, then do conditional aggregation in the outer query:

```
select
    amount_range,
    sum(type = 'A') typeA,
    sum(type = 'B') typeB,
    sum(type = 'C') typeC,
    sum(type = 'D') typeD,
    count(*) all_types
from (
    select t.*, 
        case 
            when amount > 1100 then '1001-1300'
            when amount >  900 then '901-1100'
            when amount >  700 then '701-900'
            else '500-700'
        end as amount_range
    from mytable
    where amount between 500 and 1300
) t
group by amount_range
```

Actually, there is no real need for a subquery. In MySQL, you can do:

```
select
    case 
        when amount > 1100 then '1001-1300'
        when amount >  900 then '901-1100'
        when amount >  700 then '701-900'
        else '500-700'
    end as amount_range,
    sum(type = 'A') typeA,
    sum(type = 'B') typeB,
    sum(type = 'C') typeC,
    sum(type = 'D') typeD,
    count(*) all_types
from mytable
where amount between 500 and 1300
group by amount_range
```

**Edit**

If you want ratios of the overall count of records, then use window functions (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select
    case 
        when amount > 1100 then '1001-1300'
        when amount >  900 then '901-1100'
        when amount >  700 then '701-900'
        else '500-700'
    end as amount_range,
    sum(type = 'A')/sum(count(*)) over() typeA_ratio,
    sum(type = 'B')/sum(count(*)) over() typeB_ratio,
    sum(type = 'C')/sum(count(*)) over() typeC_ratio,
    sum(type = 'D')/sum(count(*)) over() typeD_ratio,
    count(*)/sum(count(*)) over() all_types_ratio
from mytable
where amount between 500 and 1300
group by amount_range
```

Comment: Hi, your code worked. However, my requirement is now to get the percentage from total records.
Can you please update the answer?

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh: it is not a good practice to edit the question after answers were posted (it invalidates good answers). Since that’s a pretty simple change, I edited the answer for once.

Comment: over() is giving a syntax error when I am using it outside the MySQL workbench environment.